# Arel UpdateManager with Join creates invalid SQL - how to rephrase?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, common-table-expression, arel

Apparently there is an [issue in Arel core](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/44401), where `Arel::UpdateManager`, when performing a column update on a join, does not generate the table name for the update column. It results in invalid SQL.

I ran into this in a Rails 5.2 app, where I had an SQL literal UPDATE statement that I was trying to rephrase in Arel.

```sql
UPDATE observations o, names n
SET o.lifeform = n.lifeform
WHERE o.name_id = n.id
  AND o.lifeform != n.lifeform
```

In Arel, i wrote this:

```rb
names = Name.arel_table
obs = Observation.arel_table
join_source = Arel::Nodes::JoinSource.new(
  obs, [obs.create_join(names)]
)

Arel::UpdateManager.new.
  table(join_source).
  where(obs[:id].eq(names[:id]).
        and(obs[:lifeform].not_eq(names[:lifeform]))).
  set([[obs[:lifeform], names[:lifeform]]])
```

This returns:

```
Mysql2::Error: Column 'lifeform' in field list is ambiguous:
```

The problem is at the end. The SQL generated from this does not specify the table where the column is to be set.

```
UPDATE `observations` 
INNER JOIN `names` 
SET `lifeform` = `names`.`lifeform` 
WHERE (`observations`.`id` = `names`.`id`) 
AND (`observations`.`lifeform` != `names`.`lifeform`)
```

Elsewhere, Arel-generated SQL usually qualifies columns with table names to avoid ambiguity. But the [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/61d6eb119fc53678d8f5028bd73ae77e69b91fb6/activerecord/lib/arel/update_manager.rb#L24) for update_manager.rb definitely uses `Nodes::UnqualifiedColumn.new(column)`. (I have [added my description](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/44401#issuecomment-1062170399) to the Arel issue on GitHub.)

For now I'd maybe like to rephrase my Arel some other way. Is there a way to force Arel to quote the table name, similar to [`connection.quote_table_name`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Quoting.html#method-i-quote_table_name_for_assignment)?

Or would using a CTE be appropriate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess one way to do this is with ActiveRecord's `connection.update_all`.

```rb
names = Arel::Table.new(:names)
Observation.joins(:name).
 where(names[:correct_spelling_id].not_eq(nil)).
  update_all("`observations`.`name_id` = `names`.`correct_spelling_id`")
```

This generates the desired SQL:

```
UPDATE `observations` 
INNER JOIN `names` 
ON (`observations`.`name_id` = `names`.`correct_spelling_id`) 
  AND (`names`.`correct_spelling_id` IS NOT NULL) 
SET `observations`.`name_id` = `names`.`correct_spelling_id`
```

I think this is the way to go.